# Ограничить обработчик касаний ViewPager2 для определенной области

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Использую ViewPager2, проблема заключается в покрытии обработчика касаний ViewPager всего экрана, а не только внутри тех фрагментов, которые пролистываются (так мне нужно). Как результат, setOnClickListener для внешних элементов не срабатывает, в т.ч нажатие на элементы TabLayout для получения нужного фрагмента.

Что я пробовал

1. Различным образом менял вёрстку (по примерам оф.документации), помещал TabLayout и ViewPager в один контейнер, в котором параметры размеров ViewPager определялись по родителю, пробовал исп-ть CoordinatorLayout и т.п
2. В setOnClickListener внешних фрагментов блокировал обработчик касаний ViewPager (requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent)

Код xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".view.ProfileFunctionFragment">



   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#2781BD"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>


   <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id = "@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


    </FrameLayout>
```

Код фрагмента, внутри которых происходит пейджинг вложенных фрагментов

```
class ProfileFunctionFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var rootView: View
lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
lateinit var allFunctionsFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var friendsFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var wallFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var groupFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var mediaFragment: ObjectFragment
lateinit var fragmentAdapter: ViewPager2Adapter



override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_function, null, true)

    allFunctionsFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_all_function, R.id.fragment_groups_function, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsProfile)
    friendsFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_friends, R.id.function_list_friends, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsFriends)
    wallFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_wall, R.id.function_list_wall, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsWall)
    groupFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_groups, R.id.function_list_groups, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsForGroups)
    mediaFragment = ObjectFragment(R.layout.fragment_media, R.id.function_list_media, StorageFunctions.listOfFunctionsMedia)

    loadFragment(allFunctionsFragment, "all_functions_fragment")

    initViews()

    return rootView
}


@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
fun initViews(){
    viewPager = rootView.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager)
    tabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
    tabLayout.isEnabled = true
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            //если выбран tab
            when (tab!!.position) {
                0 -> loadFragment(allFunctionsFragment, "all_functions_fragment")
                1 -> loadFragment(friendsFragment, "friends_fragment")
                2 -> loadFragment(wallFragment, "wall_fragment")
                3 -> loadFragment(groupFragment, "group_fragment")
                4 -> loadFragment(mediaFragment, "media_fragment")
            }

        }


        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            //если выполнен переход от tab
        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            //если tab выбран, когда он уже активен
        }

    })


}



private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String, containerViewId: Int = R.id.nested_content) {
    MainActivity.activeFragment = tag
    childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply{
        replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag)
        commit()
    }

    

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    fragmentAdapter = ViewPager2Adapter(this)
    viewPager.isSaveEnabled = false
    viewPager.adapter = fragmentAdapter

    TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager){ tab, position ->
        when(position) {
            0 -> tab.text = "Всё"
            1 -> tab.text = "Друзья"
            2 -> tab.text = "Стена"
            3 -> tab.text = "Группы"
            4 -> tab.text = "Медиа"
        }
    }.attach()

}

}
```

Comment: Ну так обработайте нажатие там где оно обрабатывается и вызывайте нужное действие у ваших фрагментов. Этого можно добиться различными способами.

Comment: setOnClickListener назначен view-элементам, но он блокируется. Я же написал, каким образом я пытался избежать эту проблему

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему перезназначением параметров view-элементов в xml-файле и удалением обработчика в коде setOnTabClickListener (ViewPager2 берёт на себя эту задачу по дефолту)

Поместил TabLayout и ViewPager2 в LinearLayout, у которого параметры:

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation = "vertical">
```

У TabLayout:
`android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

У ViewPager:
`android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"`